How does magnetic force compare to electrical force between electrons?
How does the electrostatic force compare to the magnetic force between electrons, i.e. what is the ratio?
The force between two electrons can be described via Coulomb's Law (which decreases as the inverse square of the distance). If one electron is spin up and the other spin down, do they attract each other magnetically?  How does that attractive force compare to the electrostatic repulsion?

This is a kind of a question typical rather for physics.

I performed extensive edits to your question. You can roll these back if you don't like them. Please note you are referring to bound electrons in your post. This is worth distinguishing from free electrons. A (rough) description of interactions between free electrons can be obtained by generalizing macroscopic equations (Biot-Savart law etc). For bound electrons and inclusion of spin it's a bit more complicated.

Buck, thanks.  I'm just trying to get some intuitive feeling for how strong magnetism is.  Like I could if I compared electrostatic/gravitational forces with two electrons (or even two protons), where the electrical forces would be much stronger.  I don't have any real intuition on "how strong is magnetism".  :(  [Complicating this, is that I don't really understand magnetism itself...has always seemed like magic, compared to the "I get it" intrinsic appeal of Coulomb's Law.]

Also, thanks for trying to clean up the question, versus deleting it.  I think there is a nugget of a useful question here...despite my issues understanding magnetism, itself.  I hope some useful insight can be communicated in an answer.  Something more than "go look at Maxwell's Equations".  (Which I lack the math chops for, AND which still might not give me a physical scale insight, even if I did weed through hard math.)

To see how complicated treatement of the magnetic properties of the electron can get see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_magnetic_moment

For comparison like that you should consider some actual moving charged balls - electrons aren't them.


Can you (one?  i.e. not me) take this info from the Wiki article "The value of the electron magnetic moment (symbol μe) is −9.2847646917(29)×10−24 J⋅T−1.[1] In units of the Bohr magneton (μB), it is −1.00115965218059(13) μB" and convert it into some comparison of Coulomb's law-like repulsion/attraction?  2.  And sure the idea that the electron is stationary is maybe quantum unreasonable.  But it is in electrostatics, also, and we still compute the abstract force of point charges.  So doing the same thing.


Can you do that then, Mithron?  Tell me what the ratio of forces is for two abstract situations?  Electrostatically with two electron sized charges and magnetically with to electron-sized magnetic moments?  I just want some insight on how big magnetic forces are.  E.g. I know that electrostatic forces are bigger than gravitational ones (for primary particles).

The force ratio is distance dependent. At distance 1 nm, it is reportedly 1 : 10^7 on favour of electrostatic force.

Thanks Poutnik, for the intuition.  (Although I don't see why the force ratio would be distance dependent.  Are they both inverse square?)

They would be, but magnets are dipoles, not monopoles. Dipole-dipole interactions weaken faster.

I feel like Oliver Twist asking for more gruel, but are you sure?  If they are both inverse square, than the 1/dsq would be the same for each and factor out, in a ratio, no?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole#Field_of_a_static_magnetic_dipole - Strength of dipole decreases $1/r^3$ if distance is big enough (far field). It's because one pole is attracting and the other repelling.

Perfect, thank you.
